# Excel VBA: How To Disable Protected Sheet Dialog On Keydown

Tags: vba, excel, dialog

After doing a File > Protect Workbook > Protect Current Sheet > Unselect All > Okay

Anytime I press a keydown while viewing the sheet I get a

"The cell or chart you're trying to change is on a protected sheet." dialog.

I'd like to disable this.

I currently have a Auto_Open macro which does a Application.DisplayAlerts = False

This does not seem to help, even though I'm sure the macro is running on startup.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not unprotect the sheet or allow user to select unlocked cells? Or do you genuinely want the user to only be able to view and even if they select a cell for no alert to be raised?

Answer (score 1):

So here is a workaround by [kskinne](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/50595-possible-change-default-protected-sheet-msg.html):

1) Make sure all cells you don't want changed are locked `Format Cells > Locked`

2) Then instead of protecting worksheet use the following code in the code pane for the sheet of interest.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Locked = True Then Application.Undo

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I like this solution. I don't think switching-off `DisplayAlerts` will work. I put 
`Application.DisplayAlerts = False` into `Worksheet_Activate` event and the message still fired.

Comment: Was this helpful?